# what adapter for 12V AC 2W motor

Tags: power-supply

I found a Christmas Village building that has a motor rated at 12V AC 1.5-2W. What power-supply/adapter do I need to power this motor? It seems I can find many 12V adapters, but all would over power the 1.5-2W motor. Am I thinking about this wrong? Would a 12V AC 500ma power-supply at 6W be too much for the motor? Thanks.

Comment: same thing as a 5W night light being plugged into an outlet that can also handle a 1200W hair dryer.

Answer (score 1):

If the voltage is correct, then extra milliamps will do no harm, they will stay inside the power supply.

So the 12V 6W power supply will be fine. If you need to run a few more of those motors, then it could do that at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

12V 2W motor means, the motor requires around 2/12 = 166 mA. The 12V 6W adapter can supply up to a maximum of 6/12 = 500 mA to the load. So yes you can use it to power the motor. Because your motor requires only lesser current than that.

Comment: except when it starts up then it can demand up to 8x the rated current.